PrimeVue dropdown with search filters' value reset issue
So I have been working on a project management tool's dashboard overview, where users can filter projects, statuses, due dates, etc. As the project list is a bit larger, I decided to add a filter in the primevue dropdown following the documentation of primevue v3. In the filtering section, I have added a 'reset' button to clear out the filters. However, I cannot clear the input given in the dropdown filter of Select Project(the first dropdown). By the reset function, I can only clear the v-model values. I need to clear the filter option too.
Primevue v3 Dropdown Filter
I have tried refs to catch the dropdown and remove the input value using the handleReset function, I also tried the default primevue pkg classname of the filter finding from the browser console but these didn't work.
<script setup\>

const selectedProject = ref();
const statuses = ref();

const filterStatus = ref();
const filterDueDate = ref();
const isCalendarSelected = ref(false);

watch(selectedProject, (newVal) => {
  statuses.value = [{ name: 'All', id: '' }, ...(selectedProject.value?.statuses?.map((status) =\> ({ name: status.name, id: status.id })) || [])];
});

const selectedStatus = ref();

const projectId = ref();
const sta = ref();
const enD = ref();

const filterTasks = async () => {
  projectId.value = selectedProject.value ? selectedProject.value.id : '';
  sta.value = selectedStatus.value ? selectedStatus.value.id : '';
  enD.value = filterDueDate.value;
  fetchTasks(projectId.value, sta.value, enD.value);
};

const selectFilterDate = (newDate) => {
  isCalendarSelected.value = true;
  const date = new Date(newDate);
  filterDueDate.value = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
  filterTasks();
};

const handleDateDelete = () => {
  isCalendarSelected.value = false;
  filterDueDate.value = '';
  enD.value = '';
  filterTasks();
};

const handleFilterReset = () => {
  if(selectedProject.value || filterStatus.value || 
  filterDueDate.value) {
  selectedProject.value = '';
  filterStatus.value = '';
  filterDueDate.value = '';
  projectId.value = '';
  sta.value = '';
  selectedStatus.value = '';
  isCalendarSelected.value = false;
  filterTasks();
  }else{
  return;
 }
};
</script>

<template>
 <div class="flex gap-2 align-items-center flex-wrap" style="padding: 10px;">
  <h5 class="mb-2">Tasks</h5>
  <!-- Filter -->
  <div class="flex gap-2 flex-wrap justify-content-end filter-container">
   <Dropdown @change="filterTasks()" filter filterPlaceholder="Search Projects" v-model="selectedProject" :options="totalProjects" optionLabel="name" placeholder="Select Project" class="w-full md:w-12rem mb-2" />
   <Dropdown @change="filterTasks()" v-model="selectedStatus" :options="statuses" :disabled="!selectedProject" optionLabel="name" placeholder="Select Status" class="w-full md:w-12rem mb-2" />
   <div class="mb-2 relative w-full md:w-12rem">
    <Calendar @date-select="selectFilterDate($event)" showClear vmodel="filterDueDate" placeholder="Select Date" class="w-full md:w-12rem" />
     <p v-if="isCalendarSelected" @click="handleDateDelete" class="pi pi-times end-cross absolute cursor-pointer"></p>
   </div>
   <Button @click="handleFilterReset" label="Reset" class="mb-2" severity="secondary" />
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

Output Sample
Code

From the API, prop resetFilterOnHide makes it so the filter never saves its value. It would be the only way to affect the filter box functionality as far as I know. It's not exposed for manipulation otherwise and would require a request to the PrimeVue developers to change.

How did I miss that!! Adding resetFilterOnHide worked. Thanks, buddy.
